# MVC5 Easiest way to search items and add to list using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax, viewmodel

I'm trying to build a shopping cart type function where an order header is shown and the user can search and add items to a list.

I would prefer this be done using ajax to reduce postback time.
There are 3 table elements, Items, Order, Order_Items

So essentially a searchable list with add button/links on the left of the screen and a list area on the right which is then to be saved when alterations are finished?

is this best achieved with partial views passing to and fro? or using a view model all on one page that updates each others elements? or by another way that's easier?

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction and optimistically hoping for some example code to show its implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great thanks for the -1 and no message, incredibly helpful in every possible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a great Ajax, MVC Partial view example here, covered everything I was looking for, hope it can help someone else.

[Using Ajax and Jquery in MVC and Partial Views](https://amit4dotnet.wordpress.com/2014/11/20/create-shopping-cart-in-mvc-using-ajax-and-jquery/)